# Cannot find librdkafka on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, apache-kafka

I am trying to get a simple Kafka consumer up and running on Heroku. I am using Node 8.11 and [node-rdkafka](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka). I have it running locally. When I try to run it on Heroku, I get this error:

```
Error: librdkafka++.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at bindings (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/librdkafka.js:10:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

I know the library is a wrapper for librdkafka and it looks like it just can't find it. According to the [list of things](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages) preinstalled on Heroku Ubuntu instance, it looks like librdkafka-dev and librdkafka1 are installed. I don't know how to use those, or if something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Confluent librdkafka package.

Add this to your Aptfile:

`:repo:deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.confluent.io/deb/4.0 stable main`

Still having issues after doing this, but they are different issues and it looks like I'm closer.